# Apache rewrite rule 301 - deal with subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site that I want to make sure always shows up as `www.mydomain.org` even if the user visits by typing `mydomain.org`. I understand that the best way to do this is to use a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file. I've been trying this and the rule is 'working' but not as I would like. Here's the rewrite rule that I've put in my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teachersplanner.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.teachersplanner.org/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

The problem is that my hosting has a public_html folder into which my code goes and the rewrite rule tags this onto the end of the URL provided by the user.

Here's what I mean:

- User enters `www.mydomain.org` and all works fine
- User enters `mydomain.org` and the URL is converted to `www.mydomain.org/public_html`

Can anyone explain how to stop the rewrite from adding the public_html on the end of the URL?

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located, is it in the `public_html` folder or above it? // Maybe setting a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) could fix this.

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the folder above the public_html folder. Will look into RewriteBase - unless you could provide a suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Maybe this will fix your public_html problem too.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but this gives me the same problems!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capturing URI use `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teachersplanner\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.teachersplanner.org%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,NE]
```